# What does this Java syntax, where it looks like the method is parameterized, mean?

Tags: java, generics

Here is the code I'm looking at (using Google's ImmutableMap)

```
ImmutableMap.<String,String>of();
```

What does this mean? What is the significance of doing

```
Class.<GenericType>methodName()?
```

Answer (score 5):

[`ImmutableMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) is a generic class with two type parameters, `K` and `V`. This syntax gives the concrete values for the two parameters, both being `String` in this case.

So the above returns an empty map of `String` to `String`.

See [JLS 15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) which among other things says a method invokation is

```
MethodInvocation:
     TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )
```

Here the Type Arguments are `String` and `String`

Answer (score 3):

It's used to specify the generic type(s) when type inference does not work, for example:

```
Map<String, String> m = ImmutableMap.of();
Map<String, String> m2 = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().build();
```

It parameterizes the generic type(s) of the method's return value.

Comment: Cool. This seems almost like casting. Would this be the same as Map<String,String> m2 = (Map<String,String>) ImmutableMap.builder().build()?

Comment: I don't have an IDE (or any editor and a JDK) handy right now, but I _think_ it doesn't compile.

Comment: No, providing type arguments is better than a generic cast. A generic cast is meaningless (`ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` are the same class and so cast would not catch that these are incompatible types). Providing generic types allows the compiler to ensure type safety at compile time.

Comment: @FrankPavageau I believe unparameterised statement will be allowed to compile. It will return a raw `Map` (if it cannot infer the type arguments), which you are allowed to cast (for reasons of backwards compatibility). But you are correct that you are not allowed to cast one parameterised type to another.